ASP.NET webforms issue with gridview not showing
I have an interesting issue. I have a simple webform that pulls data from the database and displays the data in a gridview control (webforms).
It works fine on my computer, but I did a screen sharing session with the user and the gridview control does not show for the user. The query that it uses returns results.
I looked at the browser settings and Javascript is enabled in their browser. As far as I know only this user is having the issue? Any ideas?

Gee, nothing much provided that would help anyone here beyond wild guessing.  Is there any kind of filtering based say on the user's login? Can you try their login and see what you get?
